# What is the time by/in your watch?

Tags: prepositions

what is the time **by/in** your watch?   (my book says **by**)

the tired travelers are sitting **in/under** the shade of a banyan tree  (book says **in**)

I believe

sentence 1 **in** should come

sentence 2 **under** should come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By* in *by your watch* has the idiomatic meaning of "according to".  *Time in your watch* is not idiomatic.

You sit **under** a tree and **in** the tree's shade.  Since the tree's shade hits the ground, *under the shade* would be underground.  Probably not what you want.

Your book is correct on both counts.

Comment: I would think that *What is the time by your watch?* is a figure speech asking for the time in general (and not *the time shown on a/any watch*).

Comment: @Matsmath It's not a figure of speech, since it asks literally what the time is according to your watch.  I don't know what it means to ask for the time in general because every time I ask for the time, I get a specific time.

Comment: Let me try again: I can ask: *What is the time?*; or *According to my watch, it is 4PM. What is the time **in** your watch?* (=shown on your watch, asking a specific time); or *I think its around 4PM. What is the time **by** your watch?* (=meaning that I don't care whether you know the time by owning a watch and having a glance at it, or you happen to have a smartphone showing it to you, or there is a wall-clock visible by you (but not by me) (=asking the time in general, not specifically the time shown by a nearby watch).

Comment: @Matsmath You have got me quite confused - *by* = *according to*.

Comment: Ignoring relativistic effects, there is only one time, and that's what's understood as the target of an inquiry as to the time.  Of course, there are many time measuring devices of varying accuracy, so the answer you get will vary depending on who's reporting from what device.  There is no time in watches; watches only report a representation of the time.  Which could be the reason that *What's the time **in** your watch?* is not idiomatic in English.  *What is the time **by** your watch?* means *What is the time according to your watch?* Smartphones aren't involved.

Comment: @Matsmath deadrat's *by your watch* is idiomatic. *In the shade* is also idiomatic, though "under the shade" does have some [established usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waltzing_Matilda).

Comment: @deadrat I agree that it should be *by* and not *in* as regards *watch*. And whilst sitting *in the shade of a tree* is idiomatic, so, in my view is *under the shade of a tree*. I do not accept your logic about being underground - that would be *under the shadow of the tree*. We stand *in the shadow* of something, not *under the shadow*.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. I was under the impression, that the phrase *by your watch* (yes, the word watch is included!) is a figure speech, meaning "according to you", which can be used in various circumstances, like *What is the weather by your watch?* (=how is the weather in your place?) or *How is the food by your watch?* (=is the food up to your standards?) or, analogously: *What is the time by your watch?* (=what is the time according to you?). Now I think this is silly.

Comment: @WS2 I stand under the correction.  Though ngram reports modern usage favoring *in the shade* by 7:1; the google by 2:1.  The book's choice is the better one.

Comment: @Matsmath Now you're just funnin' me, right?  What kind of watches have anything to do with the local weather or comestibles?

Comment: What kind of [cats and dogs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It's+raining+cats+and+dogs!) have anything to do with heavy rain? As I *tried* to say: I *thought* that it is a figure speech/idiom.

Comment: @Matsmath Good point.  Consider the idiom *by your lights*, which is used to ask for a personal opinion or judgment on a wide range of matters:  *Is the food any good by your lights?*

Comment: @Matsmath You are confused with the idiom "on your watch".

Answer (score 0):

*What  is  the time by your  watch* is  the  usage  found  mostly  in England. I think  the  usage  came  into  practice  when  watch  was the  only source  to  tell the  time. I think  by  your  watch  means  according to your watch  but  not  tell the time  in general  which changes  from  watch  to  watch.

*What  is  the  time  in  your  watch* is  not  idiomatic.

There  are  many  ways  of   asking for the  time.

What  is  the time  or  what  time  is  it? etc

I think under the  shade  is  Indian English.

*Under the  shade*  does  not  sound  idiomatic.

*We  sit  in the  sun  or  in  the  shade* but  not  under a  shade.